# Multilevel Sankey Plot Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, sankey-diagram

I would like to create a sankey plot in power bi using the chart type `Sankey 3.1.4.0` issued by Microsoft.

I have two problems with the chart:

- I would like to sort the labels such that the order is fixed (e.g. alphabetical order)
- I would like to create a multilevel sankey plot using the columns (`VALORE_OLD`, `VALORE`, `VALORE_NEW`)

This is how it looks right now. However, when I set a filter on the order of the labels may change and I do not want it. Moreover, I would like to add a third level. How can I do it?

[image]

Here there are the data used for the chart as csv

```
index,ACCOUNT,COMPORTAMENTALE,COMPORTAMENTALE_OLD,COMPORTAMENTALE_NEW,VALORE,VALORE_OLD,VALORE_NEW,ATTITUDINALE,ATTITUDINALE_OLD,ATTITUDINALE_NEW,TRANSATO_MEDIIO,TICKET_MEDIO,FREQUENCY,RICARICHE,TRANSATO_MEDIIO_OLD,TICKET_MEDIO_OLD,FREQUENCY_OLD,RICARICHE_OLD
0,3,GAMERS,HOUSE COVER,JUMPERS,UPPER MASS,MASS,MASS,ENERGY,STD,FISSO,Low,Low,Low,High,High,High,Medium,High
1,9,NEIGHBORHOOD,GREEN,JUMPERS,TOP,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,EVO,ENERGY,DEBIT,Low,Medium,Medium,High,High,High,Low,High
2,11,NEIGHBORHOOD,JUMPERS,GREEN,MASS,MASS,MASS,EVO,EVO DIGITAL,STD,Low,High,Medium,High,High,High,Medium,Low
3,27,NEIGHBORHOOD,JUMPERS,GOURMET,BASIC,TOP,UPPER MASS,DEBIT,FISSO,FISSO,Medium,Medium,Medium,High,Low,High,Low,High
4,28,TRAVELERS,GREEN,GAMERS,MASS,UPPER MASS,TOP,MOBILE,ENERGY,ENERGY,Low,Medium,Medium,High,Low,High,High,High
5,31,GAMERS,FASHIONISTAS,JUMPERS,TOP,TOP,TOP,DEBIT,FISSO,FISSO,Low,High,High,High,Medium,High,Low,Low
6,33,HOUSE COVER,ENTERTAINMENT,FASHIONISTAS,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,MASS,FISSO,EVO DIGITAL,FISSO,Low,Medium,Medium,High,Low,High,Medium,Low
7,37,GOURMET,ENTERTAINMENT,TRAVELERS,BASIC,BASIC,BASIC,STD,EVO,FISSO,Medium,Low,Low,High,Medium,High,Low,Low
8,45,GOURMET,HOUSE COVER,HOUSE COVER,UPPER MASS,TOP,TOP,ENERGY,FIBRA,DEBIT,Medium,Low,High,High,Medium,High,Low,Low
9,51,HOUSE COVER,ENTERTAINMENT,NEIGHBORHOOD,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,MOBILE,MOBILE,ENERGY,High,Low,Medium,High,Medium,High,High,Medium
10,53,FASHIONISTAS,HOUSE COVER,GOURMET,UPPER MASS,MASS,MASS,FIBRA,DEBIT,EVO DIGITAL,Medium,Medium,Low,High,High,High,High,High
11,54,FASHIONISTAS,TRAVELERS,GAMERS,BASIC,TOP,TOP,EVO,FISSO,MOBILE,Medium,Medium,Medium,High,Low,High,Medium,Medium
12,56,GAMERS,GOURMET,TRAVELERS,MASS,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,STD,DEBIT,STD,Medium,Low,Low,High,Medium,High,Low,High
13,64,ENTERTAINMENT,GREEN,HOUSE COVER,TOP,TOP,BASIC,STD,FIBRA,EVO DIGITAL,Medium,Low,Low,High,Medium,High,Medium,Medium
14,65,FASHIONISTAS,ENTERTAINMENT,GREEN,MASS,BASIC,TOP,EVO,FIBRA,STD,High,Medium,Low,High,High,High,High,High
15,68,ENTERTAINMENT,NEIGHBORHOOD,HOUSE COVER,MASS,MASS,TOP,DEBIT,MOBILE,ENERGY,Medium,Low,High,High,Medium,High,Medium,High
16,72,NEIGHBORHOOD,FASHIONISTAS,ENTERTAINMENT,MASS,TOP,BASIC,MOBILE,FISSO,DEBIT,Medium,High,High,High,High,High,Medium,Low
17,83,TRAVELERS,FASHIONISTAS,GOURMET,BASIC,TOP,MASS,STD,STD,FISSO,High,Medium,Medium,High,Medium,High,Medium,Low
18,93,HOUSE COVER,JUMPERS,GAMERS,UPPER MASS,TOP,BASIC,MOBILE,EVO DIGITAL,EVO DIGITAL,Low,High,High,High,Medium,High,High,Medium
19,102,FASHIONISTAS,JUMPERS,TRAVELERS,BASIC,TOP,UPPER MASS,EVO,EVO,EVO,Medium,Medium,Low,High,High,High,Low,High
20,105,GAMERS,TRAVELERS,NEIGHBORHOOD,TOP,MASS,TOP,ENERGY,FIBRA,MOBILE,Medium,High,High,High,Low,High,Low,High
21,109,JUMPERS,HOUSE COVER,FASHIONISTAS,BASIC,MASS,BASIC,EVO,FIBRA,ENERGY,Low,High,Low,High,Low,High,High,High
22,116,NEIGHBORHOOD,HOUSE COVER,ENTERTAINMENT,TOP,MASS,BASIC,MOBILE,ENERGY,FISSO,Medium,High,High,High,Low,High,Low,Medium
23,122,NEIGHBORHOOD,TRAVELERS,FASHIONISTAS,MASS,UPPER MASS,BASIC,ENERGY,STD,STD,High,High,High,High,Medium,High,Medium,Low
24,125,HOUSE COVER,GOURMET,GREEN,UPPER MASS,BASIC,TOP,ENERGY,EVO DIGITAL,FIBRA,Low,High,High,High,High,High,Low,High
25,127,FASHIONISTAS,GREEN,GOURMET,MASS,TOP,BASIC,DEBIT,FISSO,EVO,Low,Low,High,High,High,High,Low,High
26,135,FASHIONISTAS,NEIGHBORHOOD,GOURMET,TOP,TOP,UPPER MASS,FIBRA,EVO DIGITAL,FIBRA,Medium,Medium,Low,High,Low,High,Low,Medium
27,149,NEIGHBORHOOD,HOUSE COVER,JUMPERS,MASS,BASIC,UPPER MASS,FIBRA,MOBILE,ENERGY,High,Low,Low,High,Low,High,Low,High
28,160,GREEN,GOURMET,GOURMET,MASS,TOP,BASIC,ENERGY,STD,STD,Low,High,High,High,Low,High,Medium,Low
29,168,GAMERS,GOURMET,NEIGHBORHOOD,BASIC,TOP,MASS,ENERGY,EVO,DEBIT,Low,Medium,High,High,Medium,High,Low,Low
30,172,GAMERS,ENTERTAINMENT,GAMERS,UPPER MASS,MASS,UPPER MASS,DEBIT,STD,STD,High,Low,High,High,Medium,High,Low,High
31,186,GREEN,NEIGHBORHOOD,GREEN,BASIC,BASIC,MASS,FIBRA,MOBILE,ENERGY,High,Medium,Medium,High,Medium,High,High,Low
32,196,FASHIONISTAS,HOUSE COVER,FASHIONISTAS,BASIC,BASIC,UPPER MASS,MOBILE,EVO,EVO DIGITAL,Low,Medium,High,High,Low,High,Low,High
33,221,FASHIONISTAS,TRAVELERS,GREEN,UPPER MASS,TOP,BASIC,STD,ENERGY,EVO DIGITAL,Medium,Medium,Medium,High,Low,High,Low,Low
34,225,ENTERTAINMENT,GAMERS,HOUSE COVER,BASIC,BASIC,BASIC,STD,MOBILE,MOBILE,High,High,Low,High,Low,High,Medium,High
35,226,TRAVELERS,ENTERTAINMENT,ENTERTAINMENT,UPPER MASS,MASS,BASIC,FISSO,MOBILE,EVO DIGITAL,Medium,Medium,Low,High,Medium,High,High,Medium
36,237,GOURMET,GREEN,JUMPERS,BASIC,BASIC,UPPER MASS,EVO DIGITAL,EVO,FIBRA,Medium,Low,High,High,Low,High,High,Medium
37,238,TRAVELERS,TRAVELERS,HOUSE COVER,MASS,TOP,UPPER MASS,FISSO,ENERGY,DEBIT,High,Low,Medium,High,Low,High,High,Medium
38,240,FASHIONISTAS,GOURMET,GREEN,BASIC,MASS,TOP,ENERGY,STD,ENERGY,Medium,High,Low,High,Low,High,High,Low
39,241,HOUSE COVER,GREEN,GREEN,TOP,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,FISSO,DEBIT,DEBIT,High,Medium,High,High,Medium,High,High,Low
40,255,FASHIONISTAS,JUMPERS,ENTERTAINMENT,MASS,TOP,MASS,FISSO,EVO,FISSO,Medium,Medium,Low,High,High,High,Low,Low
41,258,FASHIONISTAS,HOUSE COVER,GOURMET,UPPER MASS,TOP,MASS,STD,EVO,FIBRA,High,Medium,Low,High,High,High,Low,Medium
42,262,GOURMET,GOURMET,ENTERTAINMENT,BASIC,UPPER MASS,BASIC,ENERGY,EVO DIGITAL,FIBRA,Medium,Low,Low,High,High,High,Medium,Low
43,267,GAMERS,GAMERS,GOURMET,UPPER MASS,TOP,TOP,ENERGY,EVO DIGITAL,DEBIT,Medium,Low,Medium,High,Low,High,Medium,Low
44,275,FASHIONISTAS,ENTERTAINMENT,GAMERS,MASS,TOP,MASS,MOBILE,FIBRA,STD,Medium,High,Medium,High,Medium,High,Low,Low
45,283,HOUSE COVER,JUMPERS,GREEN,BASIC,BASIC,UPPER MASS,EVO DIGITAL,STD,FISSO,Medium,Medium,High,High,High,High,High,Medium
46,285,JUMPERS,JUMPERS,GAMERS,BASIC,BASIC,TOP,EVO,ENERGY,DEBIT,High,Medium,Medium,High,Low,High,Medium,Medium
47,288,GREEN,GREEN,GREEN,UPPER MASS,BASIC,UPPER MASS,DEBIT,DEBIT,EVO,High,High,Low,High,High,High,High,Medium
48,291,GREEN,NEIGHBORHOOD,ENTERTAINMENT,BASIC,MASS,BASIC,MOBILE,EVO,ENERGY,High,Medium,Medium,High,Low,High,Medium,Low
49,310,GOURMET,HOUSE COVER,JUMPERS,MASS,BASIC,MASS,FISSO,MOBILE,STD,High,High,High,High,High,High,High,Low
50,314,TRAVELERS,ENTERTAINMENT,TRAVELERS,BASIC,BASIC,MASS,EVO,MOBILE,ENERGY,Low,Low,Medium,High,Low,High,High,High
51,327,GOURMET,GAMERS,FASHIONISTAS,UPPER MASS,MASS,MASS,EVO,DEBIT,MOBILE,Low,High,Medium,High,Low,High,Medium,High
52,340,NEIGHBORHOOD,FASHIONISTAS,GREEN,TOP,BASIC,UPPER MASS,STD,FISSO,MOBILE,Low,High,Low,High,Low,High,Low,Medium
53,344,ENTERTAINMENT,HOUSE COVER,ENTERTAINMENT,BASIC,UPPER MASS,BASIC,EVO,EVO DIGITAL,EVO,Low,High,Low,High,Low,High,Medium,High
54,347,NEIGHBORHOOD,GOURMET,GAMERS,TOP,UPPER MASS,BASIC,FISSO,FIBRA,FISSO,High,Low,Medium,High,High,High,Low,Low
55,350,GREEN,ENTERTAINMENT,ENTERTAINMENT,BASIC,MASS,MASS,ENERGY,ENERGY,MOBILE,High,High,Low,High,Medium,High,High,Medium
56,362,HOUSE COVER,ENTERTAINMENT,HOUSE COVER,TOP,BASIC,BASIC,FIBRA,MOBILE,EVO DIGITAL,High,Low,Medium,High,Low,High,High,High
57,367,HOUSE COVER,GOURMET,GAMERS,TOP,MASS,TOP,DEBIT,DEBIT,DEBIT,High,Low,Low,High,Medium,High,High,High
58,370,GOURMET,GREEN,GAMERS,UPPER MASS,TOP,BASIC,STD,MOBILE,STD,High,Medium,Medium,High,Medium,High,High,Medium
59,380,GAMERS,JUMPERS,GREEN,BASIC,TOP,MASS,MOBILE,EVO,FISSO,High,Medium,Medium,High,Medium,High,High,High
60,382,GOURMET,HOUSE COVER,GOURMET,TOP,MASS,MASS,EVO,ENERGY,STD,Low,Low,Medium,High,Medium,High,Medium,Medium
61,385,GAMERS,ENTERTAINMENT,GREEN,TOP,TOP,UPPER MASS,FISSO,MOBILE,EVO,Low,High,Low,High,Low,High,Medium,High
62,386,NEIGHBORHOOD,GREEN,GREEN,UPPER MASS,MASS,MASS,DEBIT,FISSO,MOBILE,Medium,High,Medium,High,High,High,High,Medium
63,388,GOURMET,JUMPERS,TRAVELERS,BASIC,TOP,MASS,FIBRA,MOBILE,STD,High,Low,Medium,High,High,High,Low,Medium
64,389,NEIGHBORHOOD,JUMPERS,GREEN,MASS,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,EVO,MOBILE,STD,Low,Low,Low,High,Low,High,High,High
65,391,GREEN,ENTERTAINMENT,ENTERTAINMENT,UPPER MASS,MASS,MASS,STD,FISSO,MOBILE,High,High,Medium,High,High,High,High,High
66,393,TRAVELERS,ENTERTAINMENT,HOUSE COVER,BASIC,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,EVO DIGITAL,EVO,FISSO,High,Low,Low,High,High,High,Low,Low
67,404,TRAVELERS,HOUSE COVER,JUMPERS,UPPER MASS,MASS,BASIC,FIBRA,ENERGY,FIBRA,Low,High,High,High,Low,High,Low,Medium
68,415,HOUSE COVER,TRAVELERS,NEIGHBORHOOD,MASS,MASS,TOP,ENERGY,DEBIT,DEBIT,Low,High,Low,High,Medium,High,Low,Medium
69,443,ENTERTAINMENT,NEIGHBORHOOD,GREEN,BASIC,TOP,UPPER MASS,FISSO,MOBILE,EVO DIGITAL,High,Low,Medium,High,High,High,Low,Medium
70,458,FASHIONISTAS,GREEN,HOUSE COVER,BASIC,UPPER MASS,BASIC,DEBIT,FISSO,MOBILE,Low,Medium,Low,High,High,High,Medium,Low
71,478,ENTERTAINMENT,FASHIONISTAS,ENTERTAINMENT,BASIC,UPPER MASS,TOP,MOBILE,STD,EVO,Low,High,Low,High,Medium,High,Medium,Medium
72,482,NEIGHBORHOOD,FASHIONISTAS,NEIGHBORHOOD,BASIC,UPPER MASS,TOP,DEBIT,STD,EVO DIGITAL,Medium,High,High,High,High,High,High,Low
73,491,ENTERTAINMENT,GAMERS,HOUSE COVER,UPPER MASS,MASS,BASIC,ENERGY,EVO,STD,High,Low,Medium,High,Medium,High,Low,Medium
74,501,NEIGHBORHOOD,TRAVELERS,GAMERS,TOP,UPPER MASS,BASIC,STD,DEBIT,DEBIT,High,Low,Medium,High,High,High,High,High
75,520,TRAVELERS,GOURMET,GAMERS,TOP,MASS,UPPER MASS,MOBILE,MOBILE,EVO,Medium,High,Low,High,Low,High,Medium,High
76,521,TRAVELERS,TRAVELERS,HOUSE COVER,MASS,BASIC,UPPER MASS,ENERGY,EVO DIGITAL,EVO,Low,Medium,Medium,High,Low,High,High,Medium
77,523,GREEN,TRAVELERS,GAMERS,BASIC,TOP,UPPER MASS,FISSO,FISSO,FISSO,Medium,Low,Medium,High,Medium,High,Low,Medium
78,525,GOURMET,TRAVELERS,ENTERTAINMENT,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,TOP,EVO DIGITAL,STD,FIBRA,High,Medium,High,High,High,High,Low,Low
79,530,FASHIONISTAS,ENTERTAINMENT,NEIGHBORHOOD,UPPER MASS,MASS,MASS,EVO DIGITAL,EVO,FISSO,Low,Medium,Medium,High,Medium,High,High,High
80,535,JUMPERS,ENTERTAINMENT,TRAVELERS,UPPER MASS,MASS,BASIC,FISSO,FISSO,EVO,Medium,High,Low,High,Low,High,High,High
81,536,ENTERTAINMENT,NEIGHBORHOOD,JUMPERS,BASIC,TOP,MASS,FIBRA,ENERGY,DEBIT,Medium,Low,Medium,High,Medium,High,Medium,High
82,541,FASHIONISTAS,GREEN,GAMERS,MASS,UPPER MASS,MASS,STD,DEBIT,ENERGY,Medium,Low,Medium,High,Medium,High,High,Medium
83,547,GOURMET,GAMERS,GAMERS,TOP,BASIC,UPPER MASS,MOBILE,DEBIT,DEBIT,Medium,Low,High,High,Medium,High,Low,Medium
84,551,NEIGHBORHOOD,HOUSE COVER,NEIGHBORHOOD,MASS,TOP,MASS,DEBIT,ENERGY,ENERGY,High,Low,Low,High,Medium,High,Low,Low
85,556,GREEN,NEIGHBORHOOD,GAMERS,UPPER MASS,TOP,TOP,MOBILE,STD,ENERGY,High,Low,High,High,Medium,High,High,High
86,563,GREEN,JUMPERS,GOURMET,BASIC,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,DEBIT,ENERGY,STD,Low,High,Medium,High,Medium,High,Low,High
87,565,TRAVELERS,JUMPERS,GREEN,UPPER MASS,TOP,UPPER MASS,MOBILE,MOBILE,FISSO,Medium,High,High,High,Medium,High,Medium,High
88,569,NEIGHBORHOOD,HOUSE COVER,GAMERS,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,TOP,EVO,DEBIT,STD,High,High,Low,High,Medium,High,High,High
89,579,FASHIONISTAS,HOUSE COVER,TRAVELERS,BASIC,BASIC,BASIC,FIBRA,MOBILE,EVO DIGITAL,Medium,High,High,High,High,High,Medium,Low
90,581,TRAVELERS,JUMPERS,JUMPERS,MASS,UPPER MASS,BASIC,FIBRA,EVO DIGITAL,ENERGY,Low,Medium,Low,High,Low,High,Medium,High
91,584,GOURMET,JUMPERS,JUMPERS,BASIC,BASIC,BASIC,STD,STD,FIBRA,High,High,High,High,High,High,High,Low
92,598,JUMPERS,TRAVELERS,GAMERS,UPPER MASS,BASIC,UPPER MASS,EVO DIGITAL,EVO,STD,Low,Low,High,High,Low,High,High,Medium
93,614,HOUSE COVER,FASHIONISTAS,GAMERS,MASS,UPPER MASS,TOP,MOBILE,EVO DIGITAL,MOBILE,High,Low,Medium,High,Low,High,Medium,Low
94,645,FASHIONISTAS,NEIGHBORHOOD,HOUSE COVER,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,TOP,STD,EVO DIGITAL,MOBILE,Medium,Medium,High,High,Medium,High,Medium,Medium
95,647,GAMERS,ENTERTAINMENT,TRAVELERS,MASS,UPPER MASS,MASS,FISSO,STD,FIBRA,Medium,Medium,High,High,Medium,High,Medium,Low
96,653,TRAVELERS,GOURMET,TRAVELERS,MASS,UPPER MASS,TOP,FIBRA,MOBILE,FISSO,High,Medium,High,High,Low,High,Low,Low
97,657,TRAVELERS,GOURMET,GAMERS,MASS,UPPER MASS,MASS,MOBILE,FISSO,ENERGY,Low,High,High,High,Medium,High,High,High
98,659,FASHIONISTAS,FASHIONISTAS,JUMPERS,MASS,TOP,TOP,DEBIT,EVO DIGITAL,FISSO,Low,Low,High,High,Medium,High,Medium,Low
99,664,NEIGHBORHOOD,GREEN,GREEN,MASS,TOP,TOP,EVO DIGITAL,FIBRA,FISSO,High,Medium,High,High,Low,High,Medium,Low
100,667,GOURMET,HOUSE COVER,TRAVELERS,UPPER MASS,BASIC,UPPER MASS,MOBILE,ENERGY,ENERGY,Low,Medium,Medium,High,Medium,High,Medium,High
101,668,NEIGHBORHOOD,GAMERS,GOURMET,BASIC,MASS,TOP,EVO DIGITAL,DEBIT,MOBILE,Medium,High,High,High,High,High,High,Low
102,676,NEIGHBORHOOD,NEIGHBORHOOD,JUMPERS,MASS,BASIC,UPPER MASS,MOBILE,STD,FISSO,High,Medium,Medium,High,High,High,High,High
103,678,ENTERTAINMENT,TRAVELERS,JUMPERS,MASS,MASS,UPPER MASS,DEBIT,FIBRA,FIBRA,High,High,High,High,Medium,High,Medium,High
104,680,GAMERS,NEIGHBORHOOD,TRAVELERS,MASS,TOP,TOP,EVO,EVO,EVO DIGITAL,Medium,Medium,Low,High,Medium,High,Low,Low
105,719,GAMERS,JUMPERS,JUMPERS,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,MASS,FISSO,MOBILE,EVO,Medium,Low,High,High,Low,High,Medium,High
106,726,GAMERS,HOUSE COVER,GREEN,MASS,UPPER MASS,BASIC,STD,EVO,STD,Low,Medium,Medium,High,Low,High,High,Medium
107,740,GREEN,GREEN,FASHIONISTAS,BASIC,MASS,UPPER MASS,EVO,FISSO,MOBILE,Medium,Medium,Medium,High,Medium,High,High,Low
108,742,TRAVELERS,JUMPERS,GAMERS,BASIC,BASIC,MASS,EVO,MOBILE,EVO,High,High,Low,High,High,High,Medium,Low
109,744,JUMPERS,FASHIONISTAS,GREEN,TOP,UPPER MASS,MASS,FISSO,STD,MOBILE,Low,Medium,High,High,High,High,High,Medium
110,747,NEIGHBORHOOD,ENTERTAINMENT,TRAVELERS,UPPER MASS,BASIC,UPPER MASS,EVO DIGITAL,FISSO,EVO,Medium,Medium,Medium,High,Medium,High,Medium,Medium
111,751,GAMERS,GREEN,GAMERS,BASIC,UPPER MASS,TOP,FIBRA,EVO,STD,Medium,High,High,High,Low,High,Medium,High
112,761,GOURMET,JUMPERS,FASHIONISTAS,TOP,BASIC,UPPER MASS,EVO,EVO,MOBILE,Low,Low,Low,High,Low,High,Low,Medium
113,771,JUMPERS,GOURMET,JUMPERS,BASIC,BASIC,MASS,MOBILE,MOBILE,EVO DIGITAL,High,High,Low,High,Medium,High,High,Medium
114,782,HOUSE COVER,JUMPERS,GREEN,BASIC,UPPER MASS,MASS,FISSO,EVO,EVO,Medium,High,Low,High,Low,High,High,Medium
115,787,ENTERTAINMENT,JUMPERS,GOURMET,BASIC,UPPER MASS,BASIC,FIBRA,ENERGY,STD,Medium,Low,High,High,Low,High,Low,Medium
116,795,HOUSE COVER,NEIGHBORHOOD,JUMPERS,UPPER MASS,MASS,UPPER MASS,FISSO,STD,EVO,Medium,Medium,High,High,Low,High,Low,High
117,805,FASHIONISTAS,ENTERTAINMENT,ENTERTAINMENT,UPPER MASS,TOP,TOP,FIBRA,FISSO,FIBRA,Low,Medium,Low,High,High,High,Low,High
118,822,GOURMET,GAMERS,NEIGHBORHOOD,BASIC,BASIC,BASIC,MOBILE,STD,DEBIT,Medium,Low,Low,High,High,High,High,High
119,827,FASHIONISTAS,GAMERS,GAMERS,TOP,MASS,BASIC,MOBILE,STD,EVO,High,Medium,Low,High,Low,High,Medium,Medium
120,831,ENTERTAINMENT,ENTERTAINMENT,FASHIONISTAS,TOP,UPPER MASS,MASS,EVO,MOBILE,STD,Low,Low,Medium,High,Medium,High,Medium,High
121,847,TRAVELERS,GREEN,JUMPERS,BASIC,BASIC,BASIC,STD,DEBIT,FIBRA,Low,Medium,High,High,Low,High,Medium,High
122,856,GREEN,FASHIONISTAS,ENTERTAINMENT,BASIC,MASS,BASIC,FIBRA,EVO DIGITAL,MOBILE,Low,Low,High,High,High,High,Low,Medium
123,867,GOURMET,HOUSE COVER,HOUSE COVER,TOP,TOP,BASIC,EVO DIGITAL,FIBRA,ENERGY,Medium,High,Medium,High,Medium,High,Low,High
124,884,GAMERS,NEIGHBORHOOD,HOUSE COVER,UPPER MASS,TOP,UPPER MASS,MOBILE,MOBILE,ENERGY,Medium,Low,Low,High,Medium,High,High,Medium
125,887,ENTERTAINMENT,FASHIONISTAS,GREEN,UPPER MASS,BASIC,UPPER MASS,ENERGY,ENERGY,EVO DIGITAL,Medium,Low,Medium,High,Medium,High,Medium,High
126,896,NEIGHBORHOOD,ENTERTAINMENT,GREEN,BASIC,BASIC,BASIC,MOBILE,STD,ENERGY,Low,Medium,Medium,High,Medium,High,High,High
127,902,NEIGHBORHOOD,FASHIONISTAS,GREEN,BASIC,UPPER MASS,MASS,ENERGY,FISSO,STD,High,High,Low,High,Medium,High,High,High
128,916,FASHIONISTAS,GAMERS,GAMERS,TOP,UPPER MASS,BASIC,ENERGY,STD,FIBRA,High,High,Medium,High,Low,High,Medium,Medium
129,917,ENTERTAINMENT,NEIGHBORHOOD,GOURMET,MASS,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,STD,EVO,FIBRA,Medium,Medium,High,High,Low,High,Medium,Medium
130,951,GOURMET,FASHIONISTAS,TRAVELERS,MASS,MASS,BASIC,MOBILE,ENERGY,EVO DIGITAL,High,High,Low,High,High,High,Low,High
131,964,NEIGHBORHOOD,GAMERS,ENTERTAINMENT,BASIC,TOP,UPPER MASS,EVO,EVO DIGITAL,DEBIT,High,High,Low,High,Low,High,Medium,High
132,965,GREEN,JUMPERS,GAMERS,MASS,TOP,UPPER MASS,EVO,DEBIT,STD,Low,Low,High,High,Low,High,Low,High
133,966,ENTERTAINMENT,GREEN,GAMERS,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,EVO,ENERGY,MOBILE,Medium,Medium,Low,High,Medium,High,High,Medium
134,971,HOUSE COVER,GOURMET,GAMERS,UPPER MASS,TOP,UPPER MASS,MOBILE,EVO,MOBILE,High,High,High,High,High,High,Low,Low
135,985,FASHIONISTAS,ENTERTAINMENT,JUMPERS,TOP,MASS,BASIC,ENERGY,EVO,EVO,Medium,High,High,High,Low,High,Low,Low
136,15,JUMPERS,FASHIONISTAS,NEIGHBORHOOD,MASS,TOP,UPPER MASS,DEBIT,DEBIT,MOBILE,High,Medium,Medium,High,High,Medium,High,High
137,16,GAMERS,ENTERTAINMENT,FASHIONISTAS,UPPER MASS,MASS,BASIC,EVO,FISSO,MOBILE,Medium,High,High,High,High,Medium,Low,Low
138,21,HOUSE COVER,GREEN,ENTERTAINMENT,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,TOP,FISSO,ENERGY,ENERGY,High,Medium,High,High,Medium,Medium,Low,Low
139,34,JUMPERS,TRAVELERS,FASHIONISTAS,TOP,TOP,TOP,FIBRA,MOBILE,EVO,High,High,Medium,High,Medium,Medium,Medium,High
140,50,TRAVELERS,TRAVELERS,GOURMET,MASS,UPPER MASS,TOP,ENERGY,ENERGY,MOBILE,Low,Medium,High,High,Low,Medium,Low,High
141,52,ENTERTAINMENT,HOUSE COVER,HOUSE COVER,UPPER MASS,BASIC,TOP,STD,MOBILE,STD,Low,Low,High,High,High,Medium,High,Medium
142,59,ENTERTAINMENT,FASHIONISTAS,GAMERS,BASIC,BASIC,BASIC,ENERGY,FIBRA,MOBILE,Medium,Low,High,High,Low,Medium,Low,Medium
143,62,JUMPERS,JUMPERS,TRAVELERS,UPPER MASS,TOP,BASIC,EVO DIGITAL,DEBIT,STD,Medium,Medium,High,High,Low,Medium,Low,Medium
144,76,NEIGHBORHOOD,ENTERTAINMENT,GAMERS,TOP,TOP,UPPER MASS,EVO,EVO,FIBRA,Medium,High,Low,High,Low,Medium,Low,Medium
145,80,HOUSE COVER,TRAVELERS,HOUSE COVER,BASIC,TOP,BASIC,DEBIT,EVO,MOBILE,Medium,Medium,Low,High,Low,Medium,Medium,Medium
146,85,HOUSE COVER,TRAVELERS,TRAVELERS,TOP,MASS,UPPER MASS,ENERGY,STD,EVO DIGITAL,Medium,Low,High,High,Medium,Medium,High,Low
147,91,GAMERS,NEIGHBORHOOD,HOUSE COVER,TOP,MASS,TOP,MOBILE,FIBRA,DEBIT,High,High,Low,High,Medium,Medium,Medium,High
148,99,NEIGHBORHOOD,ENTERTAINMENT,GOURMET,MASS,TOP,TOP,EVO,EVO,STD,Medium,High,Low,High,High,Medium,Low,High
149,110,NEIGHBORHOOD,GREEN,JUMPERS,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,MASS,ENERGY,DEBIT,EVO,Medium,Low,Low,High,Low,Medium,High,Low
150,128,ENTERTAINMENT,ENTERTAINMENT,TRAVELERS,MASS,MASS,MASS,FISSO,EVO,STD,Medium,Medium,High,High,High,Medium,High,Low
151,134,GOURMET,GAMERS,HOUSE COVER,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,BASIC,FISSO,MOBILE,FISSO,High,High,High,High,Medium,Medium,Medium,Medium
152,141,NEIGHBORHOOD,GAMERS,HOUSE COVER,TOP,BASIC,BASIC,FISSO,STD,EVO,Medium,Medium,Medium,High,Medium,Medium,High,Low
153,178,JUMPERS,GAMERS,HOUSE COVER,MASS,TOP,MASS,STD,EVO DIGITAL,STD,Medium,High,High,High,Medium,Medium,High,High
154,181,GREEN,HOUSE COVER,TRAVELERS,BASIC,UPPER MASS,TOP,DEBIT,FIBRA,DEBIT,Medium,Medium,Low,High,Medium,Medium,Low,Low
155,198,JUMPERS,HOUSE COVER,GREEN,TOP,MASS,TOP,EVO DIGITAL,MOBILE,ENERGY,Low,Medium,Low,High,Low,Medium,Low,Medium
156,217,ENTERTAINMENT,FASHIONISTAS,GREEN,MASS,BASIC,UPPER MASS,EVO,EVO,EVO,Low,Low,Medium,High,Medium,Medium,Medium,High
157,218,GOURMET,NEIGHBORHOOD,HOUSE COVER,UPPER MASS,BASIC,BASIC,FIBRA,DEBIT,ENERGY,Medium,High,Medium,High,Medium,Medium,High,High
158,254,FASHIONISTAS,ENTERTAINMENT,GREEN,MASS,MASS,BASIC,EVO DIGITAL,ENERGY,DEBIT,High,Medium,Medium,High,Medium,Medium,Low,Low
159,260,GREEN,JUMPERS,GOURMET,BASIC,BASIC,MASS,EVO,MOBILE,ENERGY,High,Low,High,High,High,Medium,High,High
160,261,GOURMET,GOURMET,TRAVELERS,MASS,TOP,BASIC,STD,EVO DIGITAL,EVO DIGITAL,High,Low,Medium,High,High,Medium,Medium,Medium
161,263,JUMPERS,TRAVELERS,FASHIONISTAS,BASIC,TOP,BASIC,DEBIT,EVO,EVO,High,High,Low,High,High,Medium,Low,Low
162,269,ENTERTAINMENT,ENTERTAINMENT,GAMERS,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,MASS,STD,STD,MOBILE,Low,High,Low,High,Low,Medium,Low,Low
163,271,GREEN,NEIGHBORHOOD,FASHIONISTAS,UPPER MASS,TOP,TOP,FIBRA,FIBRA,EVO DIGITAL,Low,Medium,High,High,Medium,Medium,Medium,High
164,272,FASHIONISTAS,NEIGHBORHOOD,JUMPERS,TOP,MASS,BASIC,FIBRA,FISSO,STD,Medium,Low,High,High,High,Medium,Low,Low
165,274,FASHIONISTAS,NEIGHBORHOOD,NEIGHBORHOOD,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,STD,MOBILE,FIBRA,Low,Low,High,High,Low,Medium,Low,Low
166,277,FASHIONISTAS,NEIGHBORHOOD,GAMERS,UPPER MASS,TOP,BASIC,FISSO,FIBRA,STD,High,Low,Low,High,High,Medium,Medium,High
167,281,GREEN,FASHIONISTAS,ENTERTAINMENT,UPPER MASS,BASIC,MASS,EVO,EVO DIGITAL,STD,Medium,Low,Low,High,Medium,Medium,Medium,Low
168,308,TRAVELERS,NEIGHBORHOOD,TRAVELERS,TOP,UPPER MASS,UPPER MASS,MOBILE,EVO,EVO,High,Low,High,High,Medium,Medium,Medium,Medium
169,317,NEIGHBORHOOD,TRAVELERS,JUMPERS,BASIC,UPPER MASS,TOP,MOBILE,MOBILE,EVO DIGITAL,High,Medium,High,High,Low,Medium,High,High
170,325,TRAVELERS,GREEN,GOURMET,MASS,TOP,UPPER MASS,DEBIT,DEBIT,STD,High,Medium,Medium,High,Low,Medium,Low,High
171,330,ENTERTAINMENT,JUMPERS,FASHIONISTAS,UPPER MASS,MASS,MASS,STD,DEBIT,FIBRA,Medium,Medium,High,High,Medium,Medium,Medium,High
172,354,GREEN,FASHIONISTAS,ENTERTAINMENT,BASIC,MASS,BASIC,MOBILE,EVO DIGITAL,EVO,Medium,High,High,High,High,Medium,High,Medium
173,364,JUMPERS,GOURMET,NEIGHBORHOOD,TOP,BASIC,BASIC,EVO,EVO DIGITAL,DEBIT,Low,Medium,Medium,High,Medium,Medium,Low,Low
174,376,GOURMET,JUMPERS,ENTERTAINMENT,TOP,BASIC,BASIC,EVO,MOBILE,MOBILE,Medium,Low,Medium,High,Medium,Medium,Medium,Medium
175,397,GAMERS,HOUSE COVER,ENTERTAINMENT,MASS,UPPER MASS,BASIC,FIBRA,DEBIT,EVO DIGITAL,Low,Low,Low,High,Low,Medium,Low,High
```